# In Nodejs sharp package how to add two image into a single image?

Tags: node.js, append, sharp

I tried to combine two images into a single image using sharp package in NodeJS but i cant is there any ways to done this with sharp package

Answer (score 5):

Use another module instead of `sharp` to append images to one another

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/join-images

Comment: The library works, however, its doc has an error, should be `import { joinImages } from 'join-images'` rather than `import joinImages from 'join-images'`

Answer (score 2):

You can put an image in front to other with the next code:

```
sharp(pathToBaseImage)
  .composite([{ input: bufferFrontImage }])
  .sharpen()
  .toBuffer()
```